# Java Face Detection Library

Tags: java, image-processing, face-detection

I have a whole bunch of images and need to filter out all that have human faces in them. Is there such a Java library that provides a single method that takes in an image as input and outputs yes or no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do face detection with [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/).  JavaCV is a Java wrapper for OpenCV.  It doesn't provided true/false but the location of the face in picture.  You could do something like:

```
public class FaceDetect {

   // Create memory for calculations
   CvMemStorage storage = null;

   // Create a new Haar classifier
   CvHaarClassifierCascade classifier = null;

   // List of classifiers
   String[] classifierName = {
                "./classifiers/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml",
                "./classifiers/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml",
                "./classifiers/haarcascade_profileface.xml" };

   public FaceDetect() {
        // Allocate the memory storage
        storage = CvMemStorage.create();

        // Load the HaarClassifierCascade
        classifier = new CvHaarClassifierCascade(cvLoad(classifierName[0]));

        // Make sure the cascade is loaded
        if (classifier.isNull()) {
                System.err.println("Error loading classifier file");
        }
   }

   public boolean find (Image value ){
        // Clear the memory storage which was used before
        cvClearMemStorage(storage);

        if(!classifier.isNull()){
                // Detect the objects and store them in the sequence
                CvSeq faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(value.getImage(), classifier,
                                storage, 1.1, 3, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);

                // Get the number of faces found.
                int total = faces.total();
                if (total > 0) {
                    return true;
                }
        }
        return false;
   }
}
```